# Allow parent div to overflow window width

Tags: html, css

I think this is a pretty basic question (at least it seems to me that it's simple). I have a div (child) inside another div (parent).

I want the parent to change its size so the child is contained inside it. Currently, no matter what I do, when the child doesn't fit the browser window, it overflows and the parent remains inside the window width boundaries.

I'm using just the code bellow:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.child {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

What can I do so the parent div grow and overflow the browser window when its child is wider than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: max-content;` to your parent div.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: max-content;
}

.child {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Update after comments:**

This solution isn't compatible with Internet Explorer and Firefox. Therefore, if possible, `display: inline-block;` is a better solution.

Comment: thanks. I'll mark this one as the correct answer, but it doesn't work in FF, IE11 etc. It's an experimental attribute value according to MDN, unfortunately, because it worked like a charm in chrome.

But, fortunately setting `display: inline-block` in the parent is a better solution to my real use case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it is indeed! I assume that in some cases, depending on the location of the parent on the page, changing the display attribute isn't an option though.